# What is the equivalent of a foreign key in mongdb in this case

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql

I have a table that contains all the users in my website.
and another table that contains reports generated by those users.
how can i ensure that the name of the person who generated the report exists in the users list ?

Answer (score 1):

This is up to your application. Before inserting or updating reports your application needs to ensure there is a matching user, and before  deleting users your application needs to ensure there are no reports that use those users.